# Running a maven profile on release:prepare only

Tags: java, git, maven, jenkins

I am starting the release process via jenkins by calling maven with

```
-Dresume=false clean release:prepare release:perform
```

Since I want to change the sourcecode (add directories and files and commit them to git) before the prepare process finishes I want to run a profile 'doAtPrepare' only at the release:prepare stage. The profile is already working at the right place but unfortunately called twice. Once at the release:prepare and once at release:perform stage. The latter produces an error when committing to a 'detached head' at git.

For running profiles at the release:perform stage only there is the configuration option 'releaseProfiles' in the maven-release-plugin which works. But I need it the other way round and did not find a solution up to now.

I tried with profile.activation.properties (profile=!doAtPrepare), tried to set variables (-D) and check them with profile.activation.properties, tried to check for existing files at profile.activation.file (which is not working because the filenames contains ${version} parameters), tried to use -P at jenkins commandline (which triggers the profile at both stages) and much more.

Anybody out there which can help me to find a working solution?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround, but not a real solution. Better suggestions are still welcome.

First, add a profile which does the desired job:

```
    <profile>
        <id>createNextDir</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <!-- whatever you want -->
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

next, add a job to the profile which creates a dummy file with fixed filename in your target-directory:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>createNextDir1</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <target>
                    <propertyfile file="target/done.lock" comment="Version ${project.version}">
                    </propertyfile>
                </target>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ant-contrib</groupId>
            <artifactId>ant-contrib</artifactId>
            <version>20020829</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

The last step is to activate the profile only when the file does not exists. Note that during release:perform the base directory is target/checkout/yourproject so one needs to reference the correct file ../../../yourproject/target/done.lock

```
<profile>
    <id>createNextDir</id>
    <activation>
        <file>
            <missing>../../../yourproject/target/done.lock</missing>
        </file>
    </activation>
    <!-- Rest of profile -->
</profile>
```